# Using a single SELECT statement with multiple JOINs to retrieve multiple one-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, join, one-to-many

Is it advisable to use a single SELECT statement with multiple JOINs to retrieve multiple one-to-many relationships? It seems that as the number of relationships grows the result of the join will grow to a unmanageable number.

For example, let's say that we have the following relationships:

- School has many teachers
- School has many students
- School has many departments

Let's say we want to retrieve a school with id=1 along with its teachers, students and departments. Here's a query for this using a single SELECT statement:

```
SELECT s.name  AS school, 
       t.name  AS teacher, 
       st.name AS student, 
       d.name  AS department 
FROM   schools s 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN teachers t 
                    ON s.id = t.SchoolId 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN students st 
                    ON s.id = st.SchoolId 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN departments d 
                    ON s.id = d.SchoolId 
WHERE  s.id = 1;
```

Suppose this school has 100 teachers, 1000 students and 10 departments. Then this query will return a million records (100 x 1000 x 10)! Instead if we did 3 seperate SELECTs, we will get the same information in 100 + 1000 + 10 = 1110 records. I can only imagine the single SELECT to be extremely slow. Is there any advantage then to doing a single SELECT? Is this a known anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Your "solution" does not get the same information. It retrieves separate lists of teachers, departments, and students, but not which student is in which teacher's class and similarly with teachers and departments.

Comment: That's correct. However relationships between teachers, students and departments is not there in the database either. It's just the set of teachers, students and departments,